# Django Template field.is_required Work Around

Tags: jquery, django, validation, forms, required

I have a django form that I'm outputing no problem.

My question is with regard to jQuery Validation.
I want to apply jQuery validation to inputs that are required.
I'm using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

There's no field.is_required that I can use in the template
so I'm using the help_text and evaluating that in my template.

Just wondering if this is the best way to go about this?

Any advise much appreciated.

Here is:

1) Form Class

```
class UserDetailsForm(forms.Form):

    city_town = forms.CharField(label='City / Town',max_length=100, required=True, help_text='*')
    state_province = forms.CharField(label='State / Province',max_length=100, required=True, help_text='*')
```

2) Form output

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
{{ field.errors }}
{{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field.help_text }} {{ field }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

3) Form jQuery Validation

```
// Form Validation Setup
{% for field in form %}
{% if field.help_text == '*' %}
$("input[name='{{ field.html_name }}']").addClass('required');
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
$("#updateProfileForm").validate();
```

Is there any better method than the this work around I'm using:

```
if field.help_text == '*'
```

I may want to use that field for a tool tip of something later
but for now I'm using an asterisk so I can use it in a loop for jQuery validation
in the template.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate through a form instance, the `__iter__` method returns a `BoundField` (that handles the rendering and other misc items).  This bound field has a field attribute that stores the actual field instance (which does store the required attribute).  So you can do

```
{% if field.field.required %}
    $("input[name='{{ field.html_name }}']").addClass('required');
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I also thought so, but actually it doesn't.

Comment: @Torsten What version are you using?

Comment: @Torsten: `field.field.required` will work.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @James Django 1.3 and it never worked before. Tested sdolan comment and this one works. I knew there was some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your model. This will add the class `'required'` to your form.

```
city_town.widget.attrs['class'] = 'required'
```

Comment: Thanks. This option is great too. Both the 1st answer and this work well for me.